# setting default value for field using concatenation function

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table where the first column and second column would be concatenated into 3rd column.

```
Id     camera_Id     Image-Id
1287   257          257-1287 .(always be concatenation of the two fields )
```

Is there any way that i can do it while creating a table or should

```
CREATE TRIGGER image_ids 
BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.Image_id = CONCAT(id ' ', camera_id);
END
```

Comment: Is this just a default value, or must the `Image-Id` **always** be a concatination of the other two fields?

Comment: always be concateantion of the two fields

Comment: The `SET` statement in the body of your trigger definition doesn't look right. Likely you want: **`SET NEW.Image_id = CONCAT(NEW.id,'-',NEW.camera_id);`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: Is there any way that I can do it while creating a table?**

**A:** No, it's not possible to declare a column with a default value like you describe, as the result of an expression that concatenates the values assigned to two other columns.

The DEFAULT value must be a constant.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html

A `BEFORE INSERT` trigger (like you have shown) is the only way to accomplish this functionality. (You may also want to consider implementing a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger as well.)

The SET statement in the body of your trigger definition doesn't look right, you likely want this:

```
    SET NEW.Image_id = CONCAT(NEW.id,'-',NEW.camera_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't do it in your insert statement for whatever reason, then a trigger is probably your only way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If `Image_Id` is **always** just a concatination of the other two columns, as stated in the comments, there's no reason to have it as another column in the table - just create a view to provide it on the fly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW image_ids_views
AS
SELECT id, camera_id, CONCAT(id, '-', camera_id) AS image_id
FROM   image_ids
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik but this Image_id  is main column where my script looks for index of the image location.can we  use concat of two fields in default can  mysql recongise this in table creation.